# DataGridView multirow select clearing on left mouse button drag and drop

Tags: c#, datagridview, multi-select

I'm trying to implement Drag & Drop for multiple rows on a standard DataGridView.

I'm selecting 3 rows holding down the control key and left mouse button. I then release the control key and what to select the rows to drag. So using the left mouse button I click and hold the button on one of the rows so I can start the drag motion.

However as soon as I click one of the rows, that row is selected and the other 2 rows are de-selected so I'm no longer moving 3 rows.

How can I get round this problem? I would only expect the row to be highlighted again if I released the left mouse button (without the ctrl key). This is how windows explorer works.

I'm using C#4.0 in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this exact issue on a project - how to allow the user to use standard methods to select a bunch of rows in a datagridview and then drag the selection to another datagrid view and drop it. I was able to build on an idea from http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/338594/Drag-drop-multiple-selected-rows-of-datagridview-w which is just to subclass the DataGridView as a "draggable" DataGridView, trapping the mouse actions when the user presses the button on an already-selected row, while allowing standard behavior for all other cases:

```
public partial class DraggableDataGridView : System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView {

    private Rectangle dragBoxFromMouseDown;

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {

        // Trap the case where the user pressed the left mouse button on an already-selected row
        // without <shift> or <control>

        if ((e.Button & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left
            && Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.None
            && this.SelectedRows.Count > 0
            && HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex >= 0
            && this.SelectedRows.Contains(this.Rows[HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex])
            ) {

                // User pressed the mouse button over an already-selected row without <shift> or <control> so we should 
                // consider drag and drop. Record a rectangle around that mouse location to possibly trigger drag
                // operation

                Debug.WriteLine("MouseDown inside selection");
                Size dragSize = SystemInformation.DragSize;
                dragBoxFromMouseDown = new Rectangle(new Point(e.X - (dragSize.Width / 2), e.Y - (dragSize.Height / 2)), dragSize);

        } else {
            // In other cases use the default behavior for datagridview
            Debug.WriteLine("MouseDown outside selection");
            dragBoxFromMouseDown = Rectangle.Empty;
            base.OnMouseDown(e);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e) {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {
        if ((e.Button & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left) {
            // If the mouse moves outside the drag limit rectangle, start the drag.
            if (dragBoxFromMouseDown != Rectangle.Empty && !dragBoxFromMouseDown.Contains(e.Location)) {
                // Proceed with the drag and drop, passing in the selected rows
                DragDropEffects dropEffect =
                        this.DoDragDrop(this.SelectedRows, DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
        }
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
    }

    public DraggableDataGridView() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe) {
        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }
}
```

Having this code, and then substituting this custom component for all my DataGridViews in forms allowed me to use these as a standard drag source, and "plug" them into the standard drop functions for other components in the usual way.

Comment: Another flavor is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942636/how-do-i-mimic-windows-explorer-multi-select-drag-n-drop-behavior-in-a-datagridv

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a much simpler solution but this should work. The whole idea is change the selected rows' BackColor to the `SelectionBackColor` and the selected rows' ForeColor to the `SelectionForeColor`. They look like they are selected. I suppose `DataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect` to get the `SelectedRows` easily instead of selecting rows by clicking on the row headers. I also suppose the `Form.KeyPreview = true`

Here is my code:

```
//This is to copy the SelectedRows every time user releases the Control key
DataGridViewRow[] selectedRows;
private void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){
     if(selectedRows == null) return;
     if(!selectedRows.Contains(dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex])){
       //Restore the BackColor and ForeColor of the selected rows
       foreach(DataGridViewRow row in selectedRows){
           row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
           row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor;
       }
     }
}
private void form_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){
  if(e.KeyCode == Keys.ControlKey){
     selectedRows = new DataGridViewRow[dataGridView.SelectedRows.Count];
     dataGridView.SelectedRows.CopyTo(selectedRows,0);
     foreach(DataGridViewRow row in selectedRows){
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor;
        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor;
     }
  }
}
```

I hope you understand the whole idea to customize it and code yourself, such as restore the `BackColor` and `ForeColor` if the dataGridView is lost focus...

I hope it helps and someone can give a better solution!