# Is it possible to extend the DataGridView control without subclassing?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

**The short version:**

Is there a way I can add properties and override the OnMouseDown / OnMouseUp functionality on the DataGridView control without creating my own control which extends the DataGridView?

**The long version (with an explanation):**

I am implementing drag and drop moving of multiple rows between grids in an existing application. I have an extended DataGridView control with the functionality I require, and it works perfectly moving rows between instances of this grid.

This is the extended DGV class code:

```
public partial class DragDropGrid : DataGridView
{
    /// <summary>
    /// When set, the mouse down event and click events don't happen until the mouse button is released.
    /// </summary>
    public bool DelayMouseDown = false;

    public int MouseDownRowIndex = -1;

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DelayMouseDown)
        {
            return;
        }
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DelayMouseDown)
        {
            base.OnMouseDown(e);
        }
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
    }
}
```

However, I also have another grid (a custom UserControl) which I need to be able to handle the same drag and drop functionality. This grid is a composite user control from our base class suite, and has a DataGridView along with a bunch of other stuff sitting on the control.

I have tried the following to implement the same functionality as the base DataGridView I have extended successfully, but have had no luck getting it to work:

- Extending my base class grid the same as the DataGridView. This
  doesn't work as overriding the MouseDown / MouseUp methods does so on the
  custom UserControl, not the DataGridView which sits on the control - so
  clicking the grid doesn't fire the overridden methods.
- Updating the base class grid with the properties / overridden methods.
  This has the same problem as above; the MouseDown / MouseUp is 
  overriding the UserControl's methods, so clicking the DataGridView on
  the control doesn't hit the overridden methods.

I was hoping to just add the properties and override the methods on the whole DataGridView class, so that the DGV on the custom UserControl would pick up the functionality alongside the other DataGridView controls.

Help!

Comment: Can you not add handlers directly to the mouse operations? If your DataGridView is called dgv, then  dgv.OnCellMouseDown += MyHandlerMethodName?

Comment: I might not have been clear enough in the question, but I don't want to subscribe to the MouseDown / MouseUp events, I want to override the OnMouseDown / OnMouseUp functions for the grid. I'll edit in the extension code to the question so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Apologies, I had misunderstood. From a cursory glance, Luaan's answer looks to be a good approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your user control has a `DataGridView` inside anyway.

So instead of binding the existing `MouseDown`/`MouseUp` events etc. (which indeed are events of the user control, not the grid), just add new events to your user control, and let them pass down to the grid view. For example:

```
public event MouseEventHandler GridMouseDown 
{ 
  add { dataGrid.MouseDown += value; }
  remove { dataGrid.MouseDown -= value; }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Okay, since you ask specifically about overriding the `OnMouseDown` methods, the answer is simple: creating a derived type is the only way.

There are some very dirty hacks you could use to get around this, but that's a bad idea for something as trivial as this.

Comment: I think you may have been misled by my poor choice of words - sorry! I don't want to do anything with the events (even though I did say events - I'll edit that to clarify); I was to override the **underlying functionality** which handles the mouse down and mouse up events. The idea being that I can set the 'DelayMouseDown' property to true in the mouse down event in my application, then on a subsequent click, the mouse down doesn't happen (therefore the selection doesn't get changed) until the mouse button is released.

Comment: @PauLF Okay, that's not possible, then. Is there a reason why you're not using the usual drag and drop APIs?

Comment: There is a flaw with the way the DGV handles mouse clicks when attempting to use multi-selecting alongside drag and drop. For example: select multiple rows in a grid, then attempt to start a drag - the left click which begins the drag also calls the MouseDown and Click, firing the SelectionChanged, and changing the selected rows to only the one row the MouseDown occurred over. Overriding the MouseDown allows you to retain the row selection when starting a drag. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942636/how-do-i-mimic-windows-explorer-multi-select-drag-n-drop-behavior-in-a-datagridv

Comment: Just saw your edit. I'll just have to bite the bullet and change the DGV on the custom UserControl. Thanks for your help with this.